# Extend class-based UpdateView to rate objects

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following models that I need to create a form which allows for the updating of an existing Response (generated previously with a slug and then emailed to the respondent) and the creation of a `Rating` for each `CV` in `CV.objects.all()`. What's the easiest way to do this in Django. Currently I have a class-based UpdateView for Response and that's it.

```
class Response(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=32)
    submited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    submit_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class CV(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name)


class Rating(models.Model):
    cid = models.ForeignKey('CV')
    rid = models.ForeignKey('Response')
    score = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually worked out how to do this. My code was as follows in case anyone is interested.

```
def add_response(request):
    CVs = CV.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        ResForm = ResponseForm(request.POST, instance=Response())
        RatForms = [RatingForm(request.POST, prefix=str(cv.id), instance=Rating(cid=cv)) for cv in CVs]
        if ResForm.is_valid() and all([rf.is_valid() for rf in RatForms]):
            new_response = ResForm.save(commit=False)
            new_response.submit_time = datetime.now()
            new_response.submited = True
            new_response.save()
            for rf in RatForms:
                new_rating = rf.save(commit=False)
                new_rating.rid = new_response
                new_rating.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            for i, _ in enumerate(RatForms):
                RatForms[i].cv = CV.objects.filter(id=int(RatForms[i].prefix))[0]
                print RatForms[i].cv
            return render(request, 'response.html', {'response_form': ResForm, 'rating_forms': RatForms})
    else:
        ResForm = ResponseForm(instance=Response())
        RatForms = [RatingForm(prefix=str(cv.id), instance=Rating(cid=cv)) for cv in CVs]

        for i, _ in enumerate(RatForms):
            RatForms[i].cv = CV.objects.filter(id=int(RatForms[i].prefix))[0]
            print RatForms[i].cv

        return render(request, 'response.html', {'response_form': ResForm, 'rating_forms': RatForms})
```